# Meta Data driven ADF pipeline to ingestion data from multiple sources

Tags: azure-data-factory, etl, staging

I am designing ADF solution to read multiple source folder from DataLake raw layer, I need to build a config file where I can manage dynamically which file/folder to load, and date range to load

i.e. The structure of the folder in the container as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQj7B.png)

Like above screenshot I need to load the file into raw to staging layer dynamically having config file assigning the path and file types. we are receiving multiple types of files csv, json, etc.

any solution please share

I am starting new design

Comment: Can you provide how your target layer folder structure should be? and what you have you tried so far? any errors or blockers?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula, I am looking for some approach here if someone done already, the answer to your question is I am reading the files as per Year, Month, Day format folder structure.

src1->2024 -> 03 ->22
src2->2024 -> 03 ->22

I need maintain a JSON file and ADF will read from the to go and pickup data from appropriate folder and type of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, first you need to generate a file containing the list of required source file paths.

To generate that file, use dataflow. First take a `DelimitedText` file and give the path till your root container with no Column delimiter in it. Give this dataset as source of the dataflow.

[image]

You mentioned that your source files are in the directory structure like `root(crm)/src1/2024/03/22/`. So, give the wild card file path as per the structure  `*/*/*/*/*`. Add a column `filepath` in the source settings.

[image]

Import the projection and check the data preview. You will get two columns in which one contains the file paths of all types of source files.

[image]

Next, use aggregate transformation and use **groupBy** on the `filepath` column. In the aggregate section create a new column `count` and take count of filepath (`count(filepath)`) column for sample.

[image]

It will give all distinct filepaths and their count. Next use a select transformation and remove the extra `count` column from the flow.

[image]

Now, take a **derivedColumn** transformation to the `filepath` column and use expression `dropLeft(filepath,1)` in it. This will remove starting `/` in every row.

[image]

Now, take a [`filter transformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-filter) and filter out the required file paths. You can use [Dataflow expression and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions) as per your date ranges condition in the filter transformation.

Next, take another `DelimitedText` dataset as sink of the dataflow and give the file path till the **temporary container** in the dataset. Here, make sure you remove the **First row as Header** checkbox.

[image]

Go to the sink settings of the dataflow and follow the below configurations.

[image]

Upon executing the dataflow from the pipeline, the `filepaths.csv` file will be generated like below with required filepaths.

[image]

After the dataflow activity, take a **copy activity in the pipeline with two Binary datasets as source and sink of it**. Give the path till the source container (root `crm`) in the source Binary dataset and till the target root container in the target Binary dataset.

In the copy activity source, select **List of files** option and give the above `filepaths.csv` file.

[image]

Now, execute the pipeline and all the paths in the `filepaths.csv` file will be copied to the target container maintaining the same file structure.

[image]